# Missing field in the Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, exchange-server

Is there a field or anyway to retreave the smtp server of a user in the Active Directory?

**Edit1**: Using Exchange of course thanks vinny ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the 'homeMTA' attribute. It'll give you a DN like this:

CN=Microsoft MTA,CN=SERVERNAME,...<*snip*>...,DC=com

EDIT: I'm assuming you're using Exchange(?)

Comment: Yes using Exchange, important Edit there ^^

Comment: the stmp serveur is "CN=SERVERNAME" of the 'homeMTA' attribute?

Comment: Sorry, yes. It'll be the short name, though (at least it is here). You'll have to grab the domain elsewhere.